# Перечисление как индекс для массива

Tags: массивы, delphi, pascal, enum, биоинформатика

Я могу задать в качестве индекса для массива последовательность литер алфавита, вот так:

```
type
  ArRange = 'a'..'z';
var
  ar: array[ArRange] of integer;
  c:ArRange;
```

а затем использовать

```
for c:='a' to 'z' do 
  begin
     i:=ar[c];
     <...>
  end;
```

Могу я как-то сузить диапазон алфавита, причём оставить из него только несколько букв (конкретно A, G, T и C)? Как в этом случае определить ArRange и массив?

Comment: Честно говоря, выбранные буквы наводят на мысль, что они должны быть значениями массива, а не индексами. Или я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: @Dmitry, при строительстве дерева у вас появляется возможность обращаться к алфафиту через последовательность, оперировать потомками становится просто удобнее. Фактически, вы не пересчитываете каждый раз порядковый номер буквы в алфавите или не используете case, а сразу получаете ссылку на потомка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не думаю, что это получится, поскольку буквы не идут по порядку. Я догадываюсь, зачем это вам :), но увы. Если это необходимо для построения дерева, можно пользоваться таким перечислением:

```
  type
    AGTCIndex = (A, C, G, T);
```

Да, для сравнения с реальной последовательностью придётся сделать соответствие, например, посредством другого массива

```
   var
     lAGTC:array[AGTCIndex] of char = ('A','C','G','T');
```

и оперировать реальными строками уже через lAGTC[C] и т.п. Это всего лишь чуть дольше, чем у вас могло бы получиться.

В любом случае, учитывайте, что и `ord(char)` и `if (c = s[i])` тратят всего лишь несколько тактов CPU, поэтому не стоит пытаться сэкономить здесь, когда есть значительно более узкие бутылочные горлышки. Микрооптимизация, на мой взгляд, - бич современного прикладного программирования.

Либо, если это нужно не для дерева или вам безразлично, сколько памяти отъедят ваши массивы, используйте

```
type
  ArRange = 'A'..'T';
var
  ar: array[ArRange] of integer;
```

и пользуйтесь только 4мя членами массива. Расточительно, разумеется.

Answer (score 5):

Альтернативный вариант, для коллекции - эмуляция массива с помощью структуры.

```
type
    TMyArr<T> = record
      private
        FValues : array[0..3] of T;

        procedure setValue( c:char; v: T); inline;
        function getValue(c: char): T;   inline;
      public
        property values[c : char]: T read getValue write setValue; default;
    end;
```

Для 4х значений наиболее эффективней будет, наверное, вручную расставить индексы, не заморачиваясь с перечислениями.

```
function TMyArr<T>.getValue(c: char): T;
begin
    case c of
        'A' : result := FValues[0];
        'C' : result := FValues[1];
        'G' : result := FValues[2];
        'T' : result := FValues[3];
        else raise EArgumentOutOfRangeException.Create('');
    end;
end;

procedure TMyArr<T>.setValue(c: char; v: T);
var idx : byte;
begin
    case c of
        'A' : idx := 0;
        'C' : idx := 1;
        'G' : idx := 2;
        'T' : idx := 3;
        else raise EArgumentOutOfRangeException.Create('');
    end;
    FValues[idx] := v;
end;
```

В использовании от массива не отличается

```
var data : TMyArr<integer>;
    c : char;
begin
    for c in ['A','C', 'G', 'T'] do begin
        data[c] := ord(c);
        writeln(data[c]);
    end;

    data['X'] := -1;    //exception
end.
```

Comment: Надо будет сравнить в профайлере - интересно!

Comment: @ViktorTomilov в целом если эмулировать обычный массив, то раза в 2 медленнее.  [я сравнивал когда то очень давно](http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_5801.html)

Comment: ссыль не та, сравнивал [тут](http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_4442.html), но не совсем то, конечно. ептить, 7 лет прошло.

Answer (score 1):

Почему не использовать для этого словарь? Например, так:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Dialogs, System.Generics.Collections;

var
  Dict: TDictionary<Char,Integer>;

begin
  Dict := TDictionary<Char,Integer>.Create;
  try
    Dict.Add('A', 1);
    Dict.Add('G', 2);
    Dict.Add('T', 3);
    Dict.Add('C', 4);

    ShowMessage(IntToStr(Dict['T']));
  finally
    Dict.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Можно еще, как вариант, написать наследника от `TDictionary` и в конструкторе инициализировать его нужными значениями.

Comment: Идея интересная, но ресурсожрущая, увы

Comment: @PavelMayorov освобождение памяти и уничтожение объектов уже отменили?

Comment: @PavelMayorov ничего, что мы здесь **не .NET** обсуждаем?

Comment: @PavelMayorov нет, это класс из Delphi.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Начиная с версии XE3 TDictionary присутствует в Delphi: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary